# \ifcase and macro expansion

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion

There are some code. I strip out unrelated parts and get test one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystrA}{%
  a%
  \or b%
  \or c%
  \else d%
}
\newcommand{\mystrB}{%
  e%
  \or f%
  \else g%
}
\newcommand{\mystr}{\mystrA}

\newcounter{str}

\newcommand{\usestr}{%
  \ifcase\value{str}\mystr\fi%
  \addtocounter{str}{1}%
}

\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr
\end{document}
```

and after compilation with pdflatex I get:

[image: The resalt of compilation]

But I was expecting to get "a,b,c,d," as result...

So question. What is going wrong?
Why \ifcase provide nothing for values of counter more than zero?

And how right rewrite the code to get I expected?

Answer (score 9):

```
 \ifcase\value{str}\mystr\fi%
```

So TeX expands `\value` to get a number to test with `\ifcase` if that is >0 it skips ahead *not expanding* to find a matching `\or` or `\fi` and finds the `\fi` so the expansion of is empty.

I would use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystrA}[1]{%
 \ifcase#1%
  a%
  \or b%
  \or c%
  \else d%
 \fi
}
\newcommand{\mystrB}[1]{%
 \ifcase#1%
  e%
  \or f%
  \else g%
 \fi
}
\newcommand{\mystr}{\mystrA}

\newcounter{str}

\newcommand{\usestr}{%
  \mystr{\value{str}}%
  \addtocounter{str}{1}%
}

\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I use (abd how) something like \expandafter to get \mystr expanded before \ifcase will look it?

Comment: @Dimitry yes you could, although I wouldn't, having the macros with trailing unmatched `\fi` will always leave you open to weird bugs. But `\ifcase\expandafter\c@str\mystr\fi%` would do what you ask.

Answer (score 7):

TeX never sees `\or`, except when `str` has value 0.

You can force full expansion of `\mystr` before the conditional is evaluated. Beware that if `\mystrA` starts with a digit, you'd get unexpected results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mystrA}{%
  a%
  \or b%
  \or c%
  \else d%
}
\newcommand{\mystrB}{%
  e%
  \or f%
  \else g%
}
\newcommand{\mystr}{\mystrA}

\newcounter{str}

\newcommand{\usestr}{%
  \ifcase\number\value{str}\mystr\fi
  \addtocounter{str}{1}%
}

\begin{document}

\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a more flexible setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definecasesmacro}{O{str}mmm}
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #2
   {
    \int_case:nnF { \value{#1} } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{str}

\definecasesmacro{\mystr}
  {
   {0}{a}
   {1}{b}
   {2}{c}
   {4}{Hey!}
  }
  {d}

\newcommand{\usestr}{\mystr\stepcounter{str}}

\begin{document}

\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr,\usestr

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In reality it start from a digit ...and with digit it do not work :(

Comment: @Dimitry That's what I suspected; the alternative approach doesn't suffer from the problem.